# Iterate through list and going back one item

Tags: python, list, iteration

```
elementList = [ 0.05, 0.07, 0.08, 0.15, 0.25, 0.32, 0.4 ]

pathLength = elementList[-1]    

itElement = iter(elementList)
for a in itElement:
    b = next(itElement)
    c = next(itElement)
    elementSize1 = b - a
    percentOfPathElement.append(elementSize1/pathLength)
    elementSize2 = c - b
    percentOfPathElement.append(elementSize2/pathLength)
```

I have a list of points on a curve, and I need to calculate the distance between them, and append that Value/pathLength to a list.

So I need to do:

```
0.07-0.05
0.08-0.07
0.15-0.08
etc...
```

If I run the above code, when it reaches the end of the loop, it skips one calculation because "a" goes to the next value, when I really need to go back one value.

Comment: Looks like one of the few instances (I'm aware of) where a doubly-linked listed would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the adjacent difference. Making your method work:

```
itElement = iter(elementList)
a = next(itElement)
for b in itElement:
    elementSize1 = b - a
    percentOfPathElement.append(elementSize1/pathLength)
    a = b
```

Printing `a` and `b` at each iteration gives:

```
0.05 0.07
0.07 0.08
0.08 0.15
0.15 0.25
0.25 0.32
0.32 0.4
```

And `percentOfPathElement` as:

```
[0.05000000000000001, 0.024999999999999988, 0.17499999999999996, 0.25, 0.17500000000000002, 0.20000000000000004]
```

If you need to miss out the last element, change `itElement = iter(elementList)` to `itElement = iter(elementList[:-1])`.

You can also use a list comprehension such as (modified from Kasra AD):

```
percentOfPathElement = [(b - a) / pathLength for a, b in zip(elementList, elementList[1:])]
```

Or (modified from Blckknght):

```
import operator
percentOfPathElement = [diff / pathLength for diff in map(operator.sub, elementList[1:], elementList)]
```

These work in the same way as the first version, but may be harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `zip` function, to get the desire pairs then calculate the sub :

```
>>> elementList = [ 0.05, 0.07, 0.08, 0.15, 0.25, 0.32, 0.4 ]
>>> [j-i for i,j in zip(elementList,elementList[1:])]
[0.020000000000000004, 0.009999999999999995, 0.06999999999999999, 0.1, 0.07, 0.08000000000000002]
```

Comment: Why use `operator.sub` when you can just write `j - i`?

Comment: @Blckknght yep, its just a habit :)

Comment: Actually, using an operator function like that might make sense if you used `map` rather than a list comprehension: `map(operator.sub, elementList, elementList[1:])` That does almost the same thing as your code, though in Python 3 it will be a generator rather than a list.